# How to get string from an YQL response

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

I want to use a single HTTP call to get data using the Yahoo! API. I call like this using YQL

```
select * from html where url='http://time.org/zones/GMT.php' and xpath='//p[@class="head"]'
```

And I get this response

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2017-01-17T11:42:05Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "url": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "1",
     "execution-stop-time": "193",
     "execution-time": "192",
     "content": "http://time.org/zones/GMT.php"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "1",
     "execution-stop-time": "193",
     "execution-time": "192",
     "content": "http://time.org/zones/GMT.php"
    }
   ],
   "user-time": "194",
   "service-time": "383",
   "build-version": "2.0.84"
  },
  "results": {
   "p": {
    "class": "head",
    "content": "GMT - 11:29 AM (GMT)"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

So I get stuck at this step. I don't know how to get the "content": "GMT - 11:29 AM (GMT)" from this. Is there another API so I can nest this in to get the text. To tell the truth I'm making an slack command so I can only use one line of URL.

Comment: You're using javascript for read the results of your YQL result? please edit your question adding more info _(i.e how you're reading your YQL results)_.

Comment: @Mauricio Ok I will explain in details. The slack app has a function to add custom command. It is sent in either GET or POST form. It then takes the response and post on the chatbox. I want to write a custom command to get current time. I don't have resource to build server for that. So I want to use existed API and server. I am trying to use YQL API to get time from time.org but the result is returned in JSON/XML. So I want to just getting the time content inside the JSON/XML.

Comment: Trần Long, `I want to write a custom command to get current time.` in which programming language?  please **edit your question**. Comments are temporary.